# C extension for Python not working

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, module

The C extension installs fine (no warning and errors) but when I try to import it I get the following error:

> File "", line 1, in  ValueError: module functions
>   cannot set METH_CLASS or METH_STATIC

Here is the code, what could be the problem/what can I do to fix and avoid this error? Thank you very much in advance. 
EDIT: For some reason the compiler didnt show me all the warnings. I fixed the warnings and updated the code, but I still get the same error

```
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<Python.h>


PyObject *makelist(unsigned int array[], size_t size) {
    PyObject *l = PyList_New(size);
    for (size_t i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
        PyList_SET_ITEM(l, i, Py_BuildValue("i", array[i]));
    }
    return l;
}

static PyObject *module_func(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    unsigned int n;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "i", &n)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    const unsigned int size = n >> 3 + (n & 15 ? 1 : 0);
    const unsigned int arraySize = n >> 1;

    char* bitArray = (char*)malloc(size);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        *(bitArray + i) = 0b11111111;
    }

    int num;
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= ((unsigned int)sqrt(n)) >> 1; i++) {
        int ni = i - 1;
        if ((*(bitArray + (ni >> 3)) >> (ni & 7)) & 1) {
            num = (i << 1) | 1;
            for (unsigned int j = num * num; j <= n; j += num << 1) {
                *(bitArray + ((j - 3) >> 4)) &= ~(1 << (((j - 3) >> 1) & 7));
                // *(bitArray + ((((j - 1) >> 1) - 1) >> 3)) &= ~(1 << (((((j - 1) >> 1) - 1) >> 3) & 7));
            }
        }
    }

    unsigned int* primes = (unsigned int*)malloc((arraySize * sizeof(int)));
    *primes = 2;
    int counter = 1;
    for (unsigned int index = 1; index < arraySize; index++) {
        if ((*(bitArray + ((index - 1) >> 3)) >> ((index - 1) & 7)) & 1) {
            *(primes + counter) = (index << 1) | 1;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    *(primes + counter) = 0;
    return Py_BuildValue("O", makelist(primes, sizeof(primes)));
}

static PyMethodDef module_methods[] = {
    { "func", (PyCFunction)module_func, METH_VARARGS, NULL }
};

static struct PyModuleDef func =
{
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "module",
    "Null",
    -1,
    module_methods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_func(void) {
    return PyModule_Create(&func);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're running different code from what you posted. Try rebuilding it.

Comment: I did (see edit) but it still wont work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to null-terminate your `module_methods`:

```
static PyMethodDef module_methods[] = {
    { "func", (PyCFunction)module_func, METH_VARARGS, NULL },
    {NULL}
};
```

Python looks for a null entry to determine the end of a `PyMethodDef` array. Without the null terminator, Python doesn't know where the array ends, and it walks off the end of the array looking for more methods.

Comment: I cant f**ing belive it XD. Hours of debugging and then its this. Thank you very much for your help and sorry for potentially wasting your time.

Comment: @Ilovescience I would recommend that you take a look at Cython.  These types of errors are essentially impossible to make with Cython, and you still get the benefits of your algorithm being written in C.